# Redirect Multiple URL at a time in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-5.3, eloquent

When click a button. First **redirect to generate PDF** in new tab and also redirect in **dashboard** at a time .

Comment: You're expected to try something first before posting here. Share any code you've already tried and if we can help we will. No one is willing to just write the code for you.

Comment: From my understanding... You should put redirect code inside generate PDF script also. So when you redirect to generate PDF that script will do what its supposed to do and then it will redirect you to dashboard from there.

Comment: we really can't help you if you haven't tried anything try to code something if you have difficulty in that then we will try to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

As hlozancic said, I think you should open a new tab (in javascript) with the pdf url and then do a redirect to your dashboard (also in js).

Comment: Can you give me some sample of code. it will be helpful for me. Because i am new .

Comment: To open new tab (or window) in javascript : 
<a onclick="window.open('url.to_your.pdf', '_blank');window.location.replace('url.to_your.dashboard');">Click Me</a>